# How to call Transform All Templates in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2010

I have a code generation tool which is in PowerShell Script file (.ps1 files) and I call it through Package Manager console. At the end of code generation automation I need to click on "Transform All Templates" button in Solution Explorer.
I want to know if there is a way to virtualize this through PowerShell script or not?

NOTE: I couldn't find the related code through Recording Macros too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution which is sourced from here : [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/40fdebb3-83ce-4794-9eb0-bc0da7c87f39/)

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("EnvDTE")                                               
$DTE.ExecuteCommand("TextTransformation.TransformAllTemplates")
```

The above code can be executed through a PS1 file or in NuGet console.
It works in VS 2010 SP1 as I tested.